# HDP host registration failure

Tags: hortonworks-data-platform

1. On ‘Select Stack’ page under ‘Advanced Repository Options’, I checked only ‘redhat6′ which shows ‘400:Bad request’ for [HDP](http://public-repo-1.hortonworks.com/HDP/centos6/2.x/GA/2.2.0.0) and [HDP Utils](http://public-repo-1.hortonworks.com/HDP-UTILS-1.1.0.20/repos/centos6) Then I checked ‘Skip Repository Base URL validation’ and proceeded.
2. Then I added the hostnames and the id_rsa file(of the host where Ambari is running and will also be used as NN) and clicked on next.

3.Three hosts(non-Ambari) failed earlier than the other one, following is the log for one of those

```
==========================
Creating target directory…
==========================

Command start time 2015-02-11 16:03:55

Connection to l1033lab.sss.se.scania.com closed.
SSH command execution finished
host=l1033lab.sss.se.scania.com, exitcode=0
Command end time 2015-02-11 16:03:56

==========================
Copying common functions script…
==========================

Command start time 2015-02-11 16:03:56

scp /usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/ambari_commons
host=l1033lab.sss.se.scania.com, exitcode=0
Command end time 2015-02-11 16:03:56

==========================
Copying OS type check script…
==========================

Command start time 2015-02-11 16:03:56

scp /usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/ambari_server/os_check_type.py
host=l1033lab.sss.se.scania.com, exitcode=0
Command end time 2015-02-11 16:03:56

==========================
Running OS type check…
==========================

Command start time 2015-02-11 16:03:56
Cluster primary/cluster OS type is redhat6 and local/current OS type is redhat6

Connection to l1033lab.sss.se.scania.com closed.
SSH command execution finished
host=l1033lab.sss.se.scania.com, exitcode=0
Command end time 2015-02-11 16:03:57

==========================
Checking ‘sudo’ package on remote host…
==========================

Command start time 2015-02-11 16:03:57
sudo-1.8.6p3-12.el6.x86_64

Connection to l1033lab.sss.se.scania.com closed.
SSH command execution finished
host=l1033lab.sss.se.scania.com, exitcode=0
Command end time 2015-02-11 16:03:58

==========================
Copying repo file to ‘tmp’ folder…
==========================

Command start time 2015-02-11 16:03:58

scp /etc/yum.repos.d/ambari.repo
host=l1033lab.sss.se.scania.com, exitcode=0
Command end time 2015-02-11 16:03:58

==========================
Moving file to repo dir…
==========================

Command start time 2015-02-11 16:03:58

Connection to l1033lab.sss.se.scania.com closed.
SSH command execution finished
host=l1033lab.sss.se.scania.com, exitcode=0
Command end time 2015-02-11 16:03:58

==========================
Copying setup script file…
==========================

Command start time 2015-02-11 16:03:58

scp /usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/ambari_server/setupAgent.py
host=l1033lab.sss.se.scania.com, exitcode=0
Command end time 2015-02-11 16:03:59

==========================
Running setup agent script…
==========================

Command start time 2015-02-11 16:03:59
This system is not registered to Red Hat Subscription Management. You can use subscription-manager to register.
http://public-repo-1.hortonworks.com/ambari/centos6/1.x/updates/1.7.0/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 12] Timeout on http://public-repo-1.hortonworks.com/ambari/centos6/1.x/updates/1.7.0/repodata/repomd.xml: (28, ‘connect() timed out!’)
Trying other mirror.
Error: Cannot retrieve repository metadata (repomd.xml) for repository: Updates-ambari-1.7.0. Please verify its path and try again
This system is not registered to Red Hat Subscription Management. You can use subscription-manager to register.
http://public-repo-1.hortonworks.com/ambari/centos6/1.x/updates/1.7.0/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 12] Timeout on http://public-repo-1.hortonworks.com/ambari/centos6/1.x/updates/1.7.0/repodata/repomd.xml: (28, ‘connect() timed out!’)
Trying other mirror.
Error: Cannot retrieve repository metadata (repomd.xml) for repository: Updates-ambari-1.7.0. Please verify its path and try again
/bin/sh: /usr/sbin/ambari-agent: No such file or directory
{‘exitstatus': 1, ‘log': (”, None)}

Connection to l1033lab.sss.se.scania.com closed.
SSH command execution finished
host=l1033lab.sss.se.scania.com, exitcode=1
Command end time 2015-02-11 16:05:00

ERROR: Bootstrap of host l1033lab.sss.se.scania.com fails because previous action finished with non-zero exit code (1)
ERROR MESSAGE: tcgetattr: Invalid argument
Connection to l1033lab.sss.se.scania.com closed.

STDOUT: This system is not registered to Red Hat Subscription Management. You can use subscription-manager to register.
http://public-repo-1.hortonworks.com/ambari/centos6/1.x/updates/1.7.0/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 12] Timeout on http://public-repo-1.hortonworks.com/ambari/centos6/1.x/updates/1.7.0/repodata/repomd.xml: (28, ‘connect() timed out!’)
Trying other mirror.
Error: Cannot retrieve repository metadata (repomd.xml) for repository: Updates-ambari-1.7.0. Please verify its path and try again
This system is not registered to Red Hat Subscription Management. You can use subscription-manager to register.
http://public-repo-1.hortonworks.com/ambari/centos6/1.x/updates/1.7.0/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 12] Timeout on http://public-repo-1.hortonworks.com/ambari/centos6/1.x/updates/1.7.0/repodata/repomd.xml: (28, ‘connect() timed out!’)
Trying other mirror.
Error: Cannot retrieve repository metadata (repomd.xml) for repository: Updates-ambari-1.7.0. Please verify its path and try again
/bin/sh: /usr/sbin/ambari-agent: No such file or directory
{‘exitstatus': 1, ‘log': (”, None)}

Connection to l1033lab.sss.se.scania.com closed.
```

**The last one to failed(where Ambari runs) had the following log**

```
==========================
Creating target directory…
==========================

Command start time 2015-02-11 16:03:55

Connection to l1032lab.sss.se.scania.com closed.
SSH command execution finished
host=l1032lab.sss.se.scania.com, exitcode=0
Command end time 2015-02-11 16:03:56

==========================
Copying common functions script…
==========================

Command start time 2015-02-11 16:03:56

scp /usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/ambari_commons
host=l1032lab.sss.se.scania.com, exitcode=0
Command end time 2015-02-11 16:03:56

==========================
Copying OS type check script…
==========================

Command start time 2015-02-11 16:03:56

scp /usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/ambari_server/os_check_type.py
host=l1032lab.sss.se.scania.com, exitcode=0
Command end time 2015-02-11 16:03:56

==========================
Running OS type check…
==========================

Command start time 2015-02-11 16:03:56
Cluster primary/cluster OS type is redhat6 and local/current OS type is redhat6

Connection to l1032lab.sss.se.scania.com closed.
SSH command execution finished
host=l1032lab.sss.se.scania.com, exitcode=0
Command end time 2015-02-11 16:03:57

==========================
Checking ‘sudo’ package on remote host…
==========================

Command start time 2015-02-11 16:03:57
sudo-1.8.6p3-12.el6.x86_64

Connection to l1032lab.sss.se.scania.com closed.
SSH command execution finished
host=l1032lab.sss.se.scania.com, exitcode=0
Command end time 2015-02-11 16:03:58

==========================
Copying repo file to ‘tmp’ folder…
==========================

Command start time 2015-02-11 16:03:58

scp /etc/yum.repos.d/ambari.repo
host=l1032lab.sss.se.scania.com, exitcode=0
Command end time 2015-02-11 16:03:58

==========================
Moving file to repo dir…
==========================

Command start time 2015-02-11 16:03:58

Connection to l1032lab.sss.se.scania.com closed.
SSH command execution finished
host=l1032lab.sss.se.scania.com, exitcode=0
Command end time 2015-02-11 16:03:58

==========================
Copying setup script file…
==========================

Command start time 2015-02-11 16:03:58

scp /usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/ambari_server/setupAgent.py
host=l1032lab.sss.se.scania.com, exitcode=0
Command end time 2015-02-11 16:03:59

==========================
Running setup agent script…
==========================

Command start time 2015-02-11 16:03:59
Automatic Agent registration timed out (timeout = 300 seconds). Check your network connectivity and retry registration, or use manual agent registration.
```

The machines are having Internet access so I presume that there is no need for configuring local repositories. Are there some steps mandatory before one can install Ambari and proceed ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After spending plenty of time, I assumed that despite of having Internet connectivity, the local repositories will be needed. I installed Apache server and made my repositories accessible as per the [documentation](http://docs.hortonworks.com/HDPDocuments/Ambari-1.7.0.0/AMBARI_DOC_SUITE/index.html#Item2.6.3.4). Then, in ‘Advanced Repository Options’, replaced the web url with the local repository URL and it registered the hosts.
I'm still not sure why local repos. are needed(even the documentation mentions that those are needed only in case of limited or no Internet connectivity)

Comment: This is still true as of October 2018. I had this but last year already in previous versions. Unacceptable